# The advantage of using the execute array versus the direct bind_param method

Tags: php, data-binding, pdo

What's the advantage of using the execute array versus the direct bind_param method, i.e.

```
$stmtt = $conn->prepare($sql); 

$stmt->bindParam(':title', $_POST['title '], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two advantages that I could think of. (1) You can specified data type with `bindParam` or `bindValue`, while using execute array will treat everything as a string. Able to specified data type can be very handy in some cases. For example:

```
 // Return the correct result
 $sh = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT :offset,:length");
 $sh->bindValue(":offset", 0, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sh->bindValue(":length", 10, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $sh->execute();

 // Does not return any result, unless you set PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES to FALSE
 $sh = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM items LIMIT :offset,:length");
 $sh->execute(array(
    "offset" => 0,
    "length" => 10
 ));
```

(2) If you want to insert multiple times, `bindParam` can be easier. For example:

```
$sh = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO news_tags(news_id, tag) VALUES(:id, :tag)");
$sh->bindValue(":id", 2);
$sh->bindParam(":tag", $tag);

foreach($tags as $value) {
    $tag = $value;
    $sh->execute();
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing. maybe it's the only benefit.